# Form submission issue

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am trying to spoof a web form so that I can enter the data via C# program, rather then the website. If I know the form content, I assumed my code below would work, but it doesn't (The server-side data doesnt seem to change). This works fine if I save it as a webpage and run it in my browser however.

```
<form action="subDOB" method="POST" class="log">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="27">
<textarea class="logarea" rows="15" name="birth" spellcheck=FALSE>2/27/89
</textarea><br/><br/>
<input class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit" value="Edit info">
</form>
```

My code (in a button):

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://site.com/subDOB");//not a real site name :)
        string postData = @"id=27&birth=4/01/88";

        byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = send.Length;

        Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
        sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
        sout.Flush();
        sout.Close();

        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
        rtb.AppendText(returnvalue);// the return value is (apparently) the entire contents of the start page that I had to go through to get to the form
```

Fiddler return headers (from site):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 15:57:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.16
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Page-Speed: 1.8.31.2-3973
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
CF-RAY: 16d7753fae4a084a-IAD
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Fiddler return headers (from application):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 16:01:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d389a08fb9dda3009497a2a19a4e1d6d21411315317326; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019     23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.hackerexperience.com; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.16
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=fkgs1gdb2n329um5qio2pmf086; path=/; domain=.hackerexperience.com
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: index
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
CF-RAY: 16d77bfd415b084a-IAD
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting a web exception from the server, for instance?

Comment: @KeithPayne: I think OP states the problem in last line of the code sample (about the return value)

Comment: It is helpful to use a tool like Fiddler2 to see what the POST contains when you do it from your browser. If the website is ASP.NET then you will need to include the __VIEWSTATE item plus any cookies in the POST.

Comment: @Rilcon42 Try to catch session from your browser by Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2) and than catch your app's session and check what is the difference.

Comment: I captured the headers from both the app and the site. I think I did it correctly, but if you guys would like something different, let me know. Thanks for your help!